# Run method during class destruction

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have an MVVM Project and need to run some methods when th VM is destroyed. I'm trying this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyCleanUpmethod(object p)
    {
       // My Clean up proccess here 
       ....
    }       

    ~ MyClass()
    {
        MyCleanUpmethod(new object());
    }
}
```

My problem is that `~ MyClass()` only runs when close the entire application, I need to run it when MyClass is not used anymore during current procces.

It mean if `MyClass` is used as `Datacontext` of a window `~ MyClass()` must run when the window closes, if an instance of `MyClass` is used in other things diferent as `Datacontext`, `~ MyClass()` must run too

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface. Your destructor code then goes into the `Dispose` method which should be called by your own code. Alternatively you can use a `using` statement, which takes care of calling `Dispose` at the end of the scope. For a clean implementation of the dispose pattern take a look at the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx).

Using a finalizer is not appropriate because it is called by the garbage collector, which might be not in time (like in your case).

Comment: Tks. I'm Reading the article now.

Comment: Regarding the call to the dispose method, this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983801/how-to-use-disposable-view-models-in-wpf) may help.

Comment: After read the article just one question why if my class implements IDisposble, it doesn't ``Dispose`` Automatically when close my window?

Comment: `Dispose` is not called automatically. Rather, implementing `IDisposable` is a best practice for releasing resources. You're still responsible for calling the method. Maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502761/disposing-wpf-user-controls) can help you out.

Comment: My problem is how to call Dispose From my ``WPF`` window Before it is closing.

Comment: No, I'm using MVVM pattern, and all the logic resides at VM and don't know how to use ``using`` on ``XAML``

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding. You wouldn`t use the `using` keyword for this. That was just regarding the dispose pattern itself (which is an important thing to know). In your case, you'd probably just call `Dispose` somewhere. I'm pretty sure this should make it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13930385/568266 The only difference is that you don't have a user control.

Comment: Just a problem, I need to run something commands against some lists on ``DataContext`` but in this method ``closing``, Datacontext is ``null`` Think must reformule my question. Tks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'd also argue that this is worth another question. There has been some problems regarding the finalizer ;) Better create another question for the mvvm stuff.

Comment: Tks a lot for your help Mathias

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the destructor for managed code.
instead implement IDisposable:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    public void MyCleanUpmethod(object p)
    {
       // My Clean up proccess here 
       ....
    }       

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MyCleanUpmethod(new object());
    }
}
```

and then use the class like this:

```
using (var cls = new MyClass())
{
 //do stuff with cls
}
```

Comment: Tks for yur help. but how can I do to use ``using`` into ``XAML``?

Comment: hmm I dont know :) but my guess is that whatever handles the XAML, knows how to dispose objects that implement IDisposable

Comment: ``Dispose()`` Triggers automatically? or must be triggered manually?